# Possible to deploy a CFT with macros without creating change sets?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cli, aws-cloudformation-macro

When I use the AWS CLI "create-stack" operation on a CFT with the Serverless Transform Macro, I get a failure on CF with the following error: `User: <redacted> is not authorized to perform: cloudformation:CreateChangeSet on resource: arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-1:aws:transform/Serverless`

One way to get around this is to change the IAM permissions of my user, but I'd like to avoid having to do that unless absolutely necessary.

I am providing the `--capabilities CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND` flag when calling create-stack, and from perusing various AWS docs, I was under the impression that this will allow me to ignore the ChangeSet. Is there a way to avoid creating it entirely?